# Do the C compiler fix some obvious memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am running a toy example of C code in macOS Sierra 10.12.3, Xcode 8.2.1 and Instruments to visualise memory leaks and allocations.

It seems that either Instruments does not work properly or the compiler or run time engine is smart enough to solve a memory leakage on its own. All this unless I am doing a mistake here which is a very real 3rd option. Let me explain:

This is my code, 1st version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS 10
#define NUM_POSITIONS_BY_ELEMEN 100
#define TIMES 200


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    int *a[NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS];
    int cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < TIMES) {
        cnt++;

        for (int i=0;i < NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS ;i++) {
            a[i] = (int*)calloc(NUM_POSITIONS_BY_ELEMEN,sizeof(int));
        }

        int *p;
        for (int i=0;i < NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS ;i++) {

            //To free or access memory only on half of the positions
            //if (i % 2 == 0) {

                //To free memory
                free(a[i]);

                //Just using the memory allocated
                //p = a[i];
                //*p = 1;

            //}
        }
    }

int c = getchar();
printf("Bye, World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

[See screenshot of profile generated by Instruments for the version 1 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y47E0.jpg)
You can see that Instruments reports 2000 MALLOC operations to allocate 400 Bytes and no memory leaks. All okay

--

For version 2 all is still fine (section of code not shown remains the same as in version 1). This time I just want to free half of the allocations and Instruments reports accordingly (ie. 1000 MALLOCs are transient and 1000 are persistent) and a leakage is reported

```
 int *p;
 for (int i=0;i < NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS ;i++) {

    //To free or access memory only on half of the positions
    if (i % 2 == 0) {

       //To free memory
       free(a[i]);

       //Just using the memory allocated
       //p = a[i];
       //*p = 1;
    }
 }
```

I do not enough reputation to paste more than 2 links so will keep my credit to visualise the actual version with the error

--

It is in version 3 where things break (section of code not shown remains the same as in version 1).

```
    int *p;
    for (int i=0;i < NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS ;i++) {

        //To free or access memory only on half of the positions
        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            //To free memory
            //free(a[i]);

            //Just using the memory allocated
            //p = a[i];
            //*p = 1;

        }
    }
```

This time I would expect leakage coming from all MALLOCs and see 2000 persistent allocations. But no problem is reported. Not even the 2000 allocations are shown (Neither transient nor permanent; those allocations are not reported)

[See screenshot of profile generated by Instruments for the version 3 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJGYG.jpg)

--

So what is it happening? Is the compiler or run time smart to know that the allocated memory is not used and it decides not to allocate it?

So in version 4 I access the allocated memory to see if this "stops" the "optimisation" and it does. Instruments will report allocations and leakage properly as it did in version 2.

```
    int *p;
    for (int i=0;i < NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENS ;i++) {

        //To free or access memory only on half of the positions
        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            //To free memory
            //free(a[i]);

            //Just using the memory allocated
            p = a[i];
            *p = 1;

        }
    }
```

--

I am going back to the initial question: Is there really a memory leakage in version 3 even when Instruments is not reporting it? If there is not a memory leakage then why not?

Comment: In this case there shouldn't be any memory leak. All allocations should be freed at the end of `main`.

Comment: You should, however, get a memory leak if in the second loop you did something like `a[i] = NULL;`

Comment: It is very much possible that your compiler optimizes the case 3 so that it actually runs the while loop only once, or optimizes the calloc away completely since it is not used.

Comment: Release or debug build? Also, try zeroing `a` before main ends (it might be tricky in release builds, make sure you are using the correct way (volatile write or memset_s).

Comment: @haccks actually you can see in the code "int c = getchar();". I used this to stop the main from finishing before I read the results from Instruments. Also notice that all version of the code are tested and measure in the same way: it means the fact that main finishes cannot be the reason of fixing any leakage as the leakage was there in version 2 and 4

Comment: @FredK actually not. This case would function the same as version 3 where no allocations of memory are reported and no leakage reported

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think you are right: I have defined a pointer in the scope of the main and captured the address of each a[i] (in the loop shown in the code for version 2,3,4) and then I have assigned the int pointed to in this address to an unused variable before the end of the main block. Still no allocations or leakage reported but as soon as I use that variable (i did a printf) then the allocations and leakage are reported. That seems to indicate that the compiler thinks that if you do not use a value he does not need to create it

Comment: @MartiSanchez so you should write an answer documenting your findings and self-accept it :D

Comment: This is trivial to see by looking at the generated assembly. [Here's what the compiler does with your program](https://godbolt.org/g/HsAVOF). Uncomment a call to `free` to see changes.

Comment: Also note that other compilers (clang) may optimise away everything regardless of whether `free` is called or not, and/or the array manipulated or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in version 3 there is no memory leakage (and therefore Instruments works well).

It seems that the compiler is doing an optimisation when it concludes that the memory I am allocating is never going to be used. In this case it will generate code that does not even call `calloc`.

The ideal way to proof my statement will be to see the generated code or know enough about compilers to be confident this is the case. I cannot do neither of that. Instead I think what I say is true based on the following.

- I have analysed the size of the virtual memory used by my process and it is aligned with what Instruments is reporting and with what I will expect for each version of the code. See* below how I have done that
- I have played different version of the code as I explained in my comments from 27/Feb and as soon as I assign, free or write to standard output some of the allocated memory Instruments is reporting the `calloc` operations. It seems this instructions are telling the compiler that it cannot avoid the call to `calloc`. But when I do not do these instructions and I do not use the allocated memory or just read the values in memory (ie. read into a variable never used) the compiler is optimising and not calling `calloc`.

*This is how I read the memory consumed by the process:

- I run the process in Instruments. My process never finish as I have a getchar to stop the program. Instruments named my process as per my program name (this is visible in the tool bar. In my case MemoryLeak)
- I run `ps -e | grep  Leak` to find the pid of my process (Leak does reference the name of my program)
- I run `ps -p <pid> -ovsize`

*** Edited 6/March/17: Based on the comment by @n.m. posted on 5/March to the original question we can see that the code generated by the (a) compiler does not call `calloc` in the version 3 of the code.